# How to Prevent Multiple Login Of Same Credentials in Laravel 8?

Tags: authentication, session, laravel-8, logout

I have a Laravel web app where multiple users login but I need to prevent login if the user has already logged.

I know that Laravel has a method (logoutOtherDevices) to logout the user when a second user (same credentials) is login.

Uncommented   `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,` in app/Http/Kernel.php.

**But I have doubt below mentioned code where to include?**

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword);

**Answer**

```
 public function authenticated(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id == 1) {
            return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
        }
        $config = DB::table('config')->get();
        /*starts*/
        $id = Session::get('selected_plan_id');

        if(empty($id))
        {
            return redirect('/user/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $selected_plan = Plan::where('plan_id', $id)->where('status', 1)->first();
    
            if ($selected_plan == null) {
                alert()->error('Your current plan is not available. Choose another plan.');
                return redirect('/user/plans');
            } else {

                if ($selected_plan == null) {
                    return view('errors.404');
                } else {

                    return redirect('/user/rediretoCheckout');
                }
            }
        }   

    }
```

you need to include Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password); win authencication code

Comment: anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the logoutOtherDevices method provided by the Auth facade. This method requires the user to confirm their current password, which your application should accept through an **input form**: Add in Controller-> Login Mehthod

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword);

[Here you will get more details](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices)

Comment: do you know to send message if logout from other devices?